# Difference of MSVC6 and MSVC 2008 in MFC Unicode programming

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, mfc

This is My code:

```
char cName[20] = {0};
int iSum = 0;
int k=0;

k=GetDlgItemText(IDC_EName,LPTSTR(cName),11);

k=_tcslen((wchar_t*)cName);
for(unsigned int i=0;i<=k;i++)
    iSum+=cName[i]-1;

m_sSerial.Format(_T("%i"), iSum);
SetDlgItemText(IDC_ESerial, (LPCTSTR)m_sSerial);
```

I tried both of them in MSVC 6 and MSVC 2008(this one recently, of course)
but

```
MSVC 6 reult = 308
and MSVC 2008 result =241.

input of both =MSVC
```

what's wrong?
why I 've got 2 different answers and how to fix it in MSVC2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do forceful typecasting. Remove all `LPTSTR`, `LPCTSTR`, `(wchar_t*)` typecasting. Declare `cName` as:

```
TCHAR cName[20] = {0};
```

This will ensure `cName` is `WCHAR` for Unicode builds and `GetDlgItemTextW` is called for Unicode builds, and `cName` would be `char` for MBCS builds and `GetDlgItemTextA` is called.